# Where does Eclipse put your apk files (that you're developing and testing)?

Tags: android, eclipse, memory, apk, updates

I've been testing an android app that I've been developing on my phone. The problem is, it seems as if every time tweak it and re-install it onto my phone, it takes up memory. That is to say, if my app is 10mb, every time I re-install it, 10mb gets used up on my phone, so eventually my phone will run out of memory storage.

What I want to do is find the location where Eclipse stores the apk files so that I can see if there are multiple copies of my apk.

Comment: Please do accept the answer in case it helped you to solve the purpose. It helps others to know that its a right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your application floder. It must be in the workspace of eclipse. Inside application, there is bin folder. The apk is generated inside bin/ folder.

In the phone, pre installed apks are kept in system/app folder and installed applications are kept in data/app folder. Your phone should be rooted to access this folder.

But you can write small code to see what apks are present in this folder:

```
File apkDir = new File("/data/app");
String[] apkFiles = apkDir.list();

for (int i = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++ ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "File: "+files[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I mean, where does Eclipse put the apk file ON YOUR PHONE. Sorry, I wasn't too clear in my title. The reason I wanna know where it stores it on your phone is so that I can check to see if it's putting copies of the same file on my phone.

Comment: @user3369935 Igonore my last commnet. It was typo. its put on data/app of root folder

Comment: @user3369935.. I have edited my answer as per your question now. Hope it helps